# Does Azure have a "Service Discovery" service like AWS

Tags: azure, microservices

There are two methods used for service discovery.

1. Client side
2. Server Side

AWS provides server side service discovery solution. Does azure also offer similar solution? How can we achieve that in azure? By using API management?

Comment: Wouldn't AKS (Azure Kubernetes Service) provide service discovery?

Answer (score 0):

High-level applications running on Azure Sphere can perform service discovery by using DNS service discovery (DNS-SD). Applications can use service discovery to find network services and perform host name resolution so they can interact with the service through the Azure Sphere firewall. Multicast DNS (mDNS) can also be used to perform peer-to-peer discovery on a local network, which is especially useful when the IP addresses and host names of the destination endpoint aren't known at design time.

You may find more information here [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure-sphere/app-development/service-discovery#:~:text=Perform%20service%20discovery%201%20Include%20header%20files%202,connections%20for%20hosts%20with%20multiple%20IP%20addresses.%20](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure-sphere/app-development/service-discovery#:%7E:text=Perform%20service%20discovery%201%20Include%20header%20files%202,connections%20for%20hosts%20with%20multiple%20IP%20addresses.%20)

Comment: In short, no, it's not like AWS at all.